# css auto height div

Tags: html, css, height

I'm building a step-by-step booking form but I'm in trouble with the height of a container. 
You can see the issue here; by step 2 (just click on the 'next' button under the first screen)

http://staging.karlienfabre.be/pocoloco/book.html

So, the css of the content div

```
.wizard>.content {
background: #f3f3f3;
display: block;
margin: .5em;
min-height: 35em;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
width: auto;
font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;}
```

I can change the overflow to auto but than it's just a scrolling div. I would like that the height of the content change by the amount of 'content' in the div. So the whole form should fit in the content div with grey background.

I can't find the issue...

Thanks in advance!

K.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that your `section` tags within the .content div are positioned absolutely. This means the parent container has no idea how big they are. Remove the absolute positioning on `.wizard>.content>.body` and it should work.

Comment: That worked out fine! Thanks, I was already struggling for a long time. And thanks for he explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I think so the problem is in the "overflow" portion. Just try out `overflow : scroll/auto`